# How to configure Openvpn server in Ubuntu 11.10 and Openvpn client in Windows 7

Tags: openvpn

I'm really new in Linux, so I have lack of knowledge about it. I would like to setup a VPN connection, I choose Openvpn as the tool, so can somebody explain me in details how to configure Openvpn server (Openvpn Access Server) in Ubuntu and Openvpn client in Windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following URL:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN

There's some great info on this page to get you started!

Regarding OpenVPN on windows, refer to the following link:

> http://openvpn.net/index.php/download.html

Documentation for OpenVPN:

> https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn